# Удила и удить

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Удила - часть оголовья лошади, чаще всего, две соединенные вместе железки, удочка - соответственно, снасть для ловли рыбы.
Вроде бы ничего общего между этими предметами нет, но называются они почему-то похоже и у них, если не ошибаюсь, один корень. А почему? Что между ними общего?

Answer (score 1):

http://library.kiwix.org/wikipedia_ru_all/A/html/У/д/и/л/Удила.html

собственно уд--это кривой. Удовлетворять чтобы.
сегодня удила-собственно-трензель в чистом виде, иначе мундштук. Кривая скоба во рту лошади, которую закладывают за зубы. Лошади иногда закусывают скобу, если плохо одета, а потом не слушаются поводьев. Скоба эта рвет мягкие части загубья лошади, травмирует зубы, короче боль адская, потому и закусывают при малейшей возможности, чтоб уменьшить боль.

Comment: Мундштук и трензель - это совершенно разные вещи!  
Кривая скоба - это как раз мундштук, а трензель боли не причиняет.

Answer (score 0):

Есть версия, что "удило" от "удить" в утраченном значении "вкладывать уду", а уда - крючок, металлическое звено узды.

Др.-р. "уда" (снасть для ловли рыбы) восходит к праславянскому *onkda, давшему старославянское "уда" (с юсом), от него - удъка. А этимологию праславянского объясняют по-разному, одно из объяснений: onk - крюк. Вывод: и удило, и удочка - от слова "крючок".

Другие говорят, что  on - приставка + корень -kda- такой же, как в "деть", получается, уда -то, что приложено, как бы приставка. И удило тоже приставляется, вкладывается.

Так что обе версии ведут к тому, что слова однокоренные.